# Do we need to use async/await keyword in controller?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, threadpool

I have a user controller like this:

```
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public UserController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
    public async Task<User> Get(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await _userService.GetUserById(id, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

and a user service:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public async Task<User> GetUserById(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await _dbContext.Users
                               .Where(a => a.Id == id)
                               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

In `UserService` I have an `async` method that returns a user by `Id`.

My question is, do we need to use `async/await` keyword in `controller` or is using `async/await` in `UserService` enough?

```
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public UserController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
    public Task<User> Get(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _userService.GetUserById(id, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: To confirm: is the question between the version of `UserController.Get` at the top vs the one at the bottom? i.e. can we elide the `await`?

Comment: Required reading: [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're only awaiting one thing, as the last line of an `async` method, and returning the result directly or not at all (i.e. not doing anything non-trivial with the result), then *yes* you can elide the `await`, by removing the `async` and `await` parts; this avoids a bit of machinery, *but* it means that if the method you're calling faults *synchronously* (specifically: it throws an exception rather than returning a task that reports a fault state), then the exception will surface slightly differently.

Avoiding this state machine can matter *if you're in an inner loop*, for example in the middle of IO code that gets called many many times per operation and you need to optimize it, but: that doesn't apply here - you're at the top of a controller. Honestly, it doesn't need optimizing: just use the `async`/`await`: it'll be more consistently correct.